# How to find duplicate value on foreach php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i'm stuck there, i want to check and find duplicate data with value[session_id] and value[customer_id]

My array like this:

```
$data = [
   [
      'session_id' => 'abcd',
      'customer_id' => '123',
      'val' => 'abcd123',
   ],
   [
      'session_id' => 'xyz',
      'customer_id' => '123',
      'val' => 'abcd123',
   ],
   [
      'session_id' => 'abcdefgh',
      'customer_id' => '123',
      'val' => 'abcd123',
   ],
   [
      'session_id' => 'abcd',
      'customer_id' => '123',
      'val' => 'abcd123',
   ],
   [
      'session_id' => 'abcdefgh',
      'customer_id' => '123',
      'val' => 'abcd123',
   ],
   [
      'session_id' => 'abcd',
      'customer_id' => '1234',
      'val' => 'abcd123',
   ],
];
```

How to use foreach and get new array checked duplicate, i want get new array like this.

```
$newArray = [
   [
      'session_id' => 'abcd',
      'customer_id' => '123',
      'val' => 'abcd123',
   ],
   [
      'session_id' => 'xyz',
      'customer_id' => '123',
      'val' => 'abcd123',
   ],
   [
      'session_id' => 'abcdefgh',
      'customer_id' => '123',
      'val' => 'abcd123',
   ],
   [
      'session_id' => 'abcd',
      'customer_id' => '1234',
      'val' => 'abcd123',
   ],
];
```

Thanks all, happy coding <3

Comment: Can you show us your approach/attempt at least?

Comment: happy coding to you, we won't do the homework for ya

Comment: Is the `value` supposed to be the exact same across all items, as in your example data? (And if it is _not_, then which one out of two duplicates would you want to keep?)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be helpful for you.

```
$newArray=array();
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $found=0;//If no duplicate found then it will be zero
    foreach ($newArray as $v) {
        if(($v['session_id']==$value['session_id'] && $v['customer_id']==$value['customer_id'])){
            // Duplicate Exist
            $found=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!$found){//No duplicate found in $newArray
        $newArray[]=$value;
    }
}
print_r($newArray);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [session_id] => abcd
            [customer_id] => 123
            [val] => abcd123
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [session_id] => xyz
            [customer_id] => 123
            [val] => abcd123
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [session_id] => abcdefgh
            [customer_id] => 123
            [val] => abcd123
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [session_id] => abcd
            [customer_id] => 1234
            [val] => abcd123
        )

)
```